# Liferay 7 hibernate dialect Incompatibility issue

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay, liferay-7

I downloaded *Liferay-7* Tomcat bundle and using Oracle 11g database. I tried adding **ojdbc6_g.jar, ojdbc14.jar** and **classes12.jar** but nothing is working. Every time getting NullPointerException because of incompatible hibernate dialect.

```
13:54:47,634 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: 00717612-6e3c-0016-1f0e-a5e81700fe44][node:410] [Inferno] closed
13:55:57,206 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:75] Determine dialect for Oracle 11.2
13:55:57,273 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:148] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
13:55:57,529 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.DirectServletRegistryUtil.clearServlets(DirectServletRegistryUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4859)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:55:57,531 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.reset(HotDeployUtil.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4859)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:55:57,542 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The system has not be activated yet.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The system has not be activated yet.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.setStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1442)
    at com.liferay.portal.bootstrap.ModuleFrameworkImpl.stopRuntime(ModuleFrameworkImpl.java:515)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay7 CE does not support oracle (and other commercial dbs). Check [this article](https://web.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/72611307) and the references for the list of supported dbs and a way to add oracle support again, or try Liferay dxp, which supports the commercial databases.